# How can I configure my DNS settings on Debian 12?

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, nameserver, resolv.conf, debian-bookworm

I'm trying to change my DNS settings on my Debian 12 VPS, and by this I mean, I want to use a public resolver like 1.1.1.1 instead of my VPS host's resolver.

I remember in Debian 11 I could just edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, and restart the `resolvconf.service` and everything would work fine.

However, on Debian 12, when I go to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` it has a big warning:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
```

So if I can't edit this file, where can I configure my resolver?

I tried reading `man resolvconf` and `man resolv.conf` but this confused me even further.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Warning (this is chatgpt obviously)

To add a custom DNS (Domain Name System) nameserver using `systemd-resolved` on a Linux system that uses systemd as its init system (such as many modern distributions like Ubuntu), you can follow these steps:

1. **Edit the systemd-resolved Configuration File**:

   Open the `systemd-resolved` configuration file for editing using a text editor like `nano` or `vi`. On most systems, this file is located at `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. You may need superuser privileges to edit this file, so use `sudo`:

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
   ```
2. **Add the Nameserver**:

   In the configuration file, you can specify the DNS servers using the `DNS` directive. If the directive does not exist, you can add it. If it already exists, you can append additional DNS servers to it.

   For example, to add Google's public DNS server (8.8.8.8) and Cloudflare's DNS server (1.1.1.1), you can do the following:

   ```
   [Resolve]
   DNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
   ```

   You can add multiple nameservers separated by spaces.
3. **Restart systemd-resolved**:

   After editing the configuration file, you should restart the `systemd-resolved` service for the changes to take effect:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
   ```
4. **Verify the Changes**:

   You can verify that your custom nameservers are in use by querying `systemd-resolved` for DNS information. Use the `systemd-resolve` command to check:

   ```bash
   sudo resolvectl status
   ```

   You should see your custom nameservers listed under "DNS Servers" in the output.

That's it! You've successfully added custom DNS nameservers using `systemd-resolved`. These changes should persist across reboots, and your system will use the specified DNS servers for name resolution.